# Unix timestamp to UTC time error in 'ggplot'

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set contains Unix timestamp column, that I need to convert in UTC. I used `as.POSIXct` to convert the column to UTC, but throws an error like

`Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(df$timestamp) : 'origin' must be supplied`

I added the `origin` as `as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")` but still getting the same error :(

I am bit new in R and kind of lost! Could someone show me some path?

Comment: Please provide some sample data e.g. with `dput(head(df$timestamp))`

Comment: Can you show the format of the 'timestamp'

Comment: .. and the code you use that is generating it. (If you truly only reference it as `as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, origin="1970-01-01")` in this one place and never reference it elsewhere, then ... something is wrong.) Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your data but `Anytime` library might be an help!

`library(anytime)`

`anytime(value)` or `anytime(table$column)`

Then you can use `as.POSIXct()` (only if it the problem is still there). Probably this is not a simplified solution but worked for me! You can follow experts advice on this.

**NOTE:** You can also use `anydate(value)` from the same library to get the date only.